How to send Push Notifications from Android to Raspberry Pi
So I have connected my Raspberry Pi to my Android phone without the need of any passkey and no interacation in terms of the Raspberry Pi, because the Pi will be headless (not able to be changed). So all connections and interactions will need to come from the Android after initial development and work out of the box.
Bluetooth connection works from the User Android device when clicked and it connects "Calls and Audio".
I want to know how to send all App Push Notifications from the Android Device, to the Raspberry Pi in real time, via Bluetooth. I will also be setting up Internet Tethering using Bluetooth.
I assume I'll need to code a custom Android App in Java to send the notifications to the Pi running a Foreground Notification service?
Please let me know how this could be done efficiently and with minimal code / user input.

Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve]. This is off-topic as written, as it's only a set of requirements, followed by a request that the Community provide a custom solution (or possibly recommendations) for you. Also, things like "efficiently" and "minimal code" are amorphous, non-quantifiable terms.
